# How to join two tables in mySQL if both table have same name for a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  require_once 'admin/include/dbconfig.php';

  $counter = 0;

  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT f_category.f_route, f_content.f_doc, 
  f_content.f_thumb, f_content.f_title FROM f_content, f_category WHERE 
  f_content.f_id = f_category.f_id AND f_id = :uid ORDER BY f_content.id 
  DESC');

  $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  extract($row);
?>
```

> ERROR - Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'f_id' in where clause is ambiguous

How to resolve..??

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried to use alias?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `f_id` of the table you want to reference here.

```
SELECT f_category.f_route, f_content.f_doc, f_content.f_thumb,f_content.f_title 
FROM f_content, f_category 
WHERE f_content.f_id = f_category.f_id AND f_content.f_id = :uid
ORDER BY f_content.id DESC
```

f_id in `...AND f_id = :uid...` should reference to either of the table here i.e. `f_content.f_id` or `f_category .f_id`

Comment: i have changed f_id =:uid to f_content.f_id = :uid

Comment: @ShivamVerma Great :) Also, please don't forget to upvote / accept the answer which are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use table name before a column or use table alias, Both of your tables have a column `f_id` so in where clause its ambiguous if you don't specify the table name or alias for table

```
SELECT b.f_route, a.f_doc,a.f_thumb, a.f_title 
FROM f_content a
JOIN f_category b ON a.f_id = b.f_id
WHERE  a.f_id = :uid 
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases for the purpose.

Also, you missed using an alias on the column name after the `AND` operator.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT b.f_route, a.f_doc, a.f_thumb, a.f_title FROM 
    f_content a, f_category b WHERE a.f_id = b.f_id AND a.f_id = :uid ORDER BY 
    a.id DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !
You can make the alias of tables.

```
SELECT 
       fca.f_route      , 
       fco.f_doc        , 
       fco.f_thumb      ,
       fco.f_title 
    FROM 
       f_content    fco , 
       f_category   fca
    WHERE 
       fco.f_id  =  fca.f_id 
    AND 
       fca.f_id  = :uid 
    ORDER BY 
       fco.id DESC
```